# minecraft moving mouse causes huge fps drop

Tags: pc, minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I move my mouse in minecraft windows 10 with rtx. It went from 90+ fps down to 0-10 fps instant! the gpu usage also decrease from 90-100% down to 5-40% depending on how fast and much I move my mouse… I have tested to reinstall the game and change the hz on the mouse but I still have the problem!

Everything worked fine but then I turned off my pc and the next day I tested it again and I had the problem for no reason. I haven't change any setting or something it's so weird.

edit: here is a video:

pc stats
gpu:  asus geforce rtx 2080 super dual evo oc
cpu:  i9 9900k
ram:    32gb
power supply:  1200W
motherboard:  asus rog maximus XI hero (wifi)
mouse:   havit ms837

Comment: I don't know too much about pcs but it did show you were playing a beta  so that could be part of the reason.

Answer (score 1):

First off, does it do the same without RTX? -
If the answer is yes, then there is something wrong with your computer. -
If the answer is no, then try updating your drivers, restarting your PC, and unplugging/replugging all the cables. You should also remember that RTX is in beta, meaning that there WILL be some issues.

Comment: thanks for answer. i already have the best / latest drivers and i tested to restart my pc.. and i still have the problem :(  what do you mean with unplugging/replugging all the cables? do you mean rebuild the whole pc or just the screen...

Comment: and when you just start the game you see the moving picture in the background, when i move my mouse the whole picture stops moving until i stop moving my mouse.

Comment: Does this only happen with rtx or all bedrock Minecraft, and I men just the obvious outside cables, not the ones inside the pc. I would also try moving your usb mouse connector

Comment: i fixed the problem, my fps counter did everything when i turned it off it works, but thanks anyway